# Marking a correct answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

Should people who ask questions always (or at least almost always) be choosing a correct answer?  Isn't it a bit impolite if they don't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) some [general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19448/etiquette-for-selecting-answers) Stack Exchange doctrine on accepting an answer. Basically, yes, you should generally do it.

I don't think it's that huge a deal if you don't, though, since community is a stronger and more meaningful endorsement of answers, in my opinion.

Comment: I have at times considered editing questions that don't yet have any answers I want to accept, to summarize where we are and what I'm still looking for, but I had thought that was rude because of the bump effect.  Now that I know that this is suggested by SE I'll do that.

Comment: @Monica The only bumping I'd consider rude is bumping for its own sake that adds *nothing* substantive.