# Should we encourage questioners to accept answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

The percentage of accepted answers on MY is currently 34.4% (you can check the latest for yourself by entering `hasaccepted:yes` then `is:question` in the search box of the main site and dividing those numbers). This puts MY in place 125 out of 136 or bottom 8% across all MY sites ([see this SE DataExplorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291743/accepted-posts-and-post-count-across-database)).

Leaving aside the valid reasons why a Judaism site might have a lower percentage of accepted answers, I wonder if we **should encourage users to accept answers a few days after asking questions**? I don't see people doing this today, maybe because they feel self-conscious about asking on questions they answered (DoubleAA [asked](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/505/11501) exactly this a few years ago).

This could become a "MY norm" the same way we have an excellent one for [welcoming new users](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/11501) which many of us use. It would have the benefits of

- giving positive feedback and the associated point credit to the responder
- hopefully encouraging responders to write more in the future
- avoiding that the Community user [bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/312691) to the homepage questions with valid answers

I am thinking of a text like

> If you are happy that one of the answers below successfully responded
>   to your question, please think of [accepting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it. This encourages
>   more answers and will give positive feedback to the responder.

If the community likes the idea, I am sure we can do much better with the proposed standard text.

Comment: The tooltip on the site switcher says there are 171 sites at the moment.   I see that query explicitly lists the sites -- looks like it could use some updates.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yes you are right - this being said MY would still be in the bottom 27% even if all newer sites had worse accept rates. If half had better rates, MY would be bottom 17%. Anyway you look at it, many other sites have better accept rates

Comment: Would not "zeh vzeh divry eloking chaim" be a reason not to insist on accepting answers?

Comment: @Aba I love this! Still sometimes it is clear one answer is much better than others but you make a very strong point.

Comment: R Sacks has written the best rebuttal to my proposal in [God Loves Those Who Argue](http://mailchi.mp/rabbisacks/shemot-5778-243525?e=981f0bf00e)

Comment: related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/marking-a-correct-answer and https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/505/prompting-for-a-chosen-answer

Comment: Independently of you question, I had the same feeling. Do we have any news regarding this issue?

Comment: @Kazibácsi there are no news but see my 3 comments above your question - feels to me that there are valid reasons **not** to pursue my proposal

Comment: The two MY posts argues the other point in my opinion, while I don't understand why encouraging people to accept a good answer may limit debate. Accepted answer can be a help for new users